# AWS RDS Performance Insights not showing SQL Queries

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I enabled Performance Insights on an existing SQL Server database (MySql 5.6.46) in AWS RDS. 
But still, it shows 0 sessions and “No active sessions in the selected time range” no matter what duration I've select from the top list.

Is there some condition I need to meet in order to have my query get recorded in Performance Insights? What're the criteria? How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Maybe your db instance is wrong?: "Performance Insights is not supported on the following DB instance classes: db.t2.micro, db.t2.small, db.t3.micro, and db.t3.small." and "On Aurora MySQL, Performance Insights is not supported on db.t2 or db.t3 DB instance classes."

Comment: Nope, it was t3.xlarge.
Btw, I sent an email to rdspi@amazon.com, and got a prompt response.
They investigated the issue and found a bug in their backend. They fixed that really quick and now I'm able to see the reports. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Glad it got sorted out.

Answer (score 9):

I created AWS Support case where AWS Engineer explained to me:

> Unfortunately, this is a known issue from our end where Performance Insights does not get enabled when it is issued in the same API call as engine version upgrade as RDS follows a priority in executing multiple requests that have been submitted as part of the same API call - for example in this case, request to enable Performance Insights and request to upgrade the instance to 11.1 version. Performance Insights call is evaluated first followed by the engine upgrade. This means that when Performance Insights request was being considered, the instance was still on the previous incompatible version, hence the request did not go through successfully.

> The workaround to resolve this issue is to disable Performance insights, wait a few minutes and then re-enable Performance Insights.

> Enabling/disabling Performance Insights does not cause an outage/downtime. The Performance Insights agent is designed to stay out of your database workloads' way. When Performance Insights detects heavy load or depleted resources, it backs off, still collecting data, but only when it is safe to do so.